# How to take picture from web camera using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webcam

Similar questions were already asked but those are not working in my case
I am building a web application(contains student registration form), i want to capture image from web camera which can be USB camera connected to PC or it will be mobile(android) camera .

i have created a button(Take Picture), when i click on that it should open a popup(bootstrap modal) on that camera should play, there is a button when i click on that it should take picture and set to  somewhere in webpage

i tried many answers but some are opening camera very first time when i open the webpage

```
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Capture Image</h>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <style>
                            #my_camera{
                                width: 320px;
                                height: 240px;
                                border: 1px solid black;
                            }
                        </style>

                        <div id="my_camera"></div>
                        <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">

                        <div id="results" ></div>

                        <!-- Webcam.min.js -->
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="webcamjs/webcam.min.js"></script>

                        <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
                        <script language="JavaScript">
                            Webcam.set({
                                width: 320,
                                height: 240,
                                image_format: 'jpeg',
                                jpeg_quality: 90
                            });
                            Webcam.attach('#my_camera');

<!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
                            function take_snapshot() {

                                // take snapshot and get image data
                                Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
                                    // display results in page
                                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                                            '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
                                });
                            }
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Captute Image</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

i expect camera shoud play when i open the popup (modal)
and button on modal "take picture" shoud take snap and set to image tag[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mom7P.jpg)

Comment: what is `webcamjs/webcam.min.js`?

Comment: There are several js is available for accessing webcam , This was working for me , Try https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: are there any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: I got solution Sir ! Thanks for your attention .